# Delay después de hacer hover en imagen

Tags: javascript, css

Tengo el siguiente código que crea un efecto de lupa para hacer zoom a una imagen, lo que quiero lograr es que al quitar el cursor de la imagen, la lupa permanezca unos miliesegundos hasta desaparecer.

Intenté aplicar `transition-delay:1s;` pero no funcionó.

Soy un poco nuevo en CSS. Les comparto mi código a continuacion

Bendiciones!

```js
var zoomer = function (){
  document.getElementById('img-zoomer-box')
    .addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {

    var original = document.getElementById('img1'),
        magnified = document.getElementById('img2'),
        style = magnified.style,
        x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft,
        y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop,
        imgWidth = original.width,
        imgHeight = original.height,
        xperc = ((x/imgWidth) * 100),
        yperc = ((y/imgHeight) * 100);

    if(x > (.01 * imgWidth)) {
      xperc += (.15 * xperc);
    };//lets user scroll past right edge of image

    if(y >= (.01 * imgHeight)) {
      yperc += (.15 * yperc);
    };//lets user scroll past bottom edge of image

    style.backgroundPositionX = (xperc - 9) + '%';
    style.backgroundPositionY = (yperc - 9) + '%';

    style.left = (x - 180) + 'px';
    style.top = (y - 180) + 'px';

  }, false);
}();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
  height: 450px;
  overflow: scroll;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}
#img-zoomer-box {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#img1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition-delay:1s;
}

#img-zoomer-box:hover, #img-zoomer-box:active {
  cursor: zoom-in;
  display: block;
}

#img-zoomer-box:hover #img2, #img-zoomer-box:active #img2 {
  opacity: 1;
}
#img2 {
  width: 340px;
  height: 340px;
  background: url('https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/iss054e022823/iss054e022823~orig.jpg') no-repeat #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  border: 4px solid whitesmoke;
  z-index: 99;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}
```

```html
<div>Hover a la imagen para Zoom</div>    
<div id="img-zoomer-box">
  <img src="https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/iss054e022823/iss054e022823~orig.jpg" id="img1" />
  <div id="img2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que el problema es que la propiedad `transition` es una propiedad abreviada de `transition-property`, `transition-duration`, `transition-timing-function` y `transition-delay`.

Por algún motivo al poner `transition` y `transition-delay` el segundo estaba siendo ignorado, así que he separado la propiedad en varias.

Pero entonces he visto que hay un problema extra: afecta al mostrar la lupa y al esconderla, haciendo que se retrase la aparición de la misma. La solución es crear dos transiciones, una de entrada y otra de salida, permitiendo diferentes efectos y tiempos:

```js
var zoomer = function (){
  document.getElementById('img-zoomer-box')
    .addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {

    var original = document.getElementById('img1'),
        magnified = document.getElementById('img2'),
        style = magnified.style,
        x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft,
        y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop,
        imgWidth = original.width,
        imgHeight = original.height,
        xperc = ((x/imgWidth) * 100),
        yperc = ((y/imgHeight) * 100);

    if(x > (.01 * imgWidth)) {
      xperc += (.15 * xperc);
    };//lets user scroll past right edge of image

    if(y >= (.01 * imgHeight)) {
      yperc += (.15 * yperc);
    };//lets user scroll past bottom edge of image

    style.backgroundPositionX = (xperc - 9) + '%';
    style.backgroundPositionY = (yperc - 9) + '%';

    style.left = (x - 180) + 'px';
    style.top = (y - 180) + 'px';

  }, false);
}();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
  height: 450px;
  overflow: scroll;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}
#img-zoomer-box {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#img1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition-delay:1s;
}

#img-zoomer-box:hover, #img-zoomer-box:active {
  cursor: zoom-in;
  display: block;
}

#img-zoomer-box:hover #img2, #img-zoomer-box:active #img2 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-duration: .2s;
}
#img2 {
  width: 340px;
  height: 340px;
  background: url('https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/iss054e022823/iss054e022823~orig.jpg') no-repeat #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  border: 4px solid whitesmoke;
  z-index: 99;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-delay: 1s;
  transition-duration: .2s;
}
```

```html
<div>Hover a la imagen para Zoom</div>    
<div id="img-zoomer-box">
  <img src="https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/iss054e022823/iss054e022823~orig.jpg" id="img1" />
  <div id="img2"></div>
</div>
```